# has_many through Rails AngularJS Restangular 'POST'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, post, has-many-through, restangular

I am looking to create a music app where users can add songs to a playlist. I have created a has_many through association, so that "playlist_songs" are added to the playlists instead of "songs"

Here is some relevant code to give you a better idea.

playlist_song.rb

```
class PlaylistSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :song
end
```

song.rb

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  has_many :playlist_songs
  has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_songs
end
```

playlist.rb

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :playlist_songs
  has_many :songs, through: :playlist_songs
end
```

Song.attribute_names

```
["id", "url", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "album_id", "song_title"]
```

PlaylistSong.attribute_names

```
["id", "playlist_id", "song_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

What I am trying to do is add a playlist_song to a specific playlist. I assumed the best way to do this would be to simply create a playlist_song, which only has the song_id and playlist_id attributes. This would reference the song URL that I need, as well as the playlist_id that the song would belong to.

I want to save the playlist_song to the URL, http://localhost:3000/api/user_profiles/1/playlists/8/song_references, that displays the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 14,
    "playlist_id": 8,
    "song_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2016-09-25T15:43:36.459Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-25T15:43:36.459Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "playlist_id": 8,
    "song_id": 3,
    "created_at": "2016-09-25T15:43:36.460Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-25T15:43:36.460Z"
  }
]
```

Which is notably different from the URL, http://localhost:3000/api/user_profiles/1/playlists/8/playlist_songs, which displays the actual song attributes in relation to a specific playlist:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "url": "https://www.song3url.mp3",
    "name": "05 Smoke Signal (Original Mix).mp3",
    "created_at": "2016-09-24T02:33:46.648Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-29T03:44:35.464Z",
    "album_id": 1,
    "song_title": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "url": "https://www.song2url.mp3",
    "name": "07 The Son Of Flynn (Remixed by Moby).mp3",
    "created_at": "2016-09-24T02:25:52.373Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-24T02:25:52.373Z",
    "album_id": 1,
    "song_title": null
  }
]
```

You can see the specific API portion of my routes.rb file below:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    # resources :newsfeed_item
    resources :chat_rooms do
      resources :chat_messages
    end
    resources :playlists do
      resources :playlist_songs
    end
    resources :songs
    resources :venue_requests
    resources :user_profiles do
      resources :libraries
      resources :playlists do
        resources :playlist_songs
        resources :song_references
      end
    end
    resources :artist_profiles do
      resources :albums do
        resources :album_songs
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the song_references_controller.rb file that is displaying the playlist_songs:

```
class Api::SongReferencesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:playlist_id])
    @playlist_songs = PlaylistSong.where(playlist_id: params[:playlist_id])
    render json: @playlist_songs, status: :ok
  end

  def new
    @playlist_song = PlaylistSong.new
  end

  def create
    @playlist_song = PlaylistSong.new(playlist_song_params)

    if @playlist_song.save
      render json: @playlist_song, status: :created
    else
      render json: @playlist_song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def playlist_song_params
    params.fetch(:song, {}).permit(:song_id, :playlist_id)
  end
end
```

And here is the PlaylistCtrl.js file that is displaying the individual playlists and songs, as well as the $scope.saveSong function I am using to save playlist_songs to the playlist:

```
(function (){
  function PlaylistCtrl($scope, $resource, $interval, Restangular, angularSoundManager) {
    $scope.addToPlaylistVisible = false;
    $scope.selectedPlaylist = Restangular.one('api/user_profiles/1/playlists', 8).all('song_references');
    $scope.allPlaylists = Restangular.all('api/playlists');

    $interval(function(){
      $scope.allPlaylists.getList().then(function(playlists) {
        $scope.playlists = playlists;
      });

        console.log("PLAYLISTS GRABBED");
    }, 1000);

    $scope.basePlaylist = Restangular.one('api/playlists', 8).all('playlist_songs');
    $scope.playlistId = '8';

    $interval(function(){
      $scope.basePlaylist.getList().then(function(songs) {
        $scope.songs = songs;
      });

      console.log("Playlist Songs GRABBED");
    }, 1000);

    $scope.setPlaylistAttributes = function(playlistId) {
      $scope.basePlaylist = Restangular.one('api/playlists', playlistId).all('playlist_songs');
      $scope.playlistId = playlistId;
      console.log("CURRENT PLAYLIST ID " + $scope.playlistId)
    }

    $scope.setSong = function(songId) {
      $scope.songId = songId;
      $scope.addToPlaylistVisible = true;
      console.log("CURRENT SONG ID " + $scope.songId)
    }

    $interval(function(){
      $scope.selectedPlaylist.getList().then(function(playlistSongs) {
        $scope.playlistSongs = playlistSongs;
      });
      console.log("Working");
    }, 1000);


    // CREATE PLAYLIST SONG (song_reference instance) - PLAYLIST ID, SONG ID (NOT SONG, BUT PLAYLIST SONG)
    $scope.saveSong = function(selectedPlaylistId) {
      $scope.selectedPlaylist = Restangular.one('api/user_profiles/1/playlists', selectedPlaylistId).all('song_references');
      $scope.selectedPlaylistId = selectedPlaylistId;
      var newSong = {
          "playlist_id": $scope.selectedPlaylistId,
          "song_id": $scope.songId,
      };
      $scope.selectedPlaylist.post(newSong).then(function(newSong){
        $scope.playlistSongs.push(newSong);
        console.log(newSong);
      })
    };

    $scope.hidePlaylists = function() {
      $scope.addToPlaylistVisible = false;
    }

  }
  angular
      .module('PlaylistCtrl', ['angularSoundManager'])
      .controller('PlaylistCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$interval', 'Restangular', PlaylistCtrl]);
})();
```

playlists/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>All Playlists</h1>

<div ng-controller="PlaylistCtrl">
  <div>
    <ul ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
      <li>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="setPlaylistAttributes(playlist.id);">{{ playlist.name }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <%= link_to "New playlist",  new_user_profile_playlist_path, data: { push: true } %>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <h3>Selected Playlist</h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="song in songs">
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" music-player="play" add-song="song">{{ song.name }}</a>
        <button ng-click="setSong(song.id);">ADD TO PLAYLIST</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button play-all="songs" data-play="false">Add all</button>
    <div ng-if="addToPlaylistVisible">
      <a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="hidePlaylists();"><img src="/assets/HUD_icons/x.png"/></a>
      <ul ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
        <li>
          <a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="saveSong(playlist.id);">{{ playlist.name }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, after selecting the correct song to be added, selecting the playlist for the song to be added to, and saving the playlist_song, it is not saving any attributes along with the playlist song.

When looking in the rails console, I get an object that looks like this:

```
=> #<PlaylistSong:0x007f9397d3c700
 id: 48,
 playlist_id: nil,
 song_id: nil,
 created_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 00:50:47 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 00:50:47 UTC +00:00>
```

But I see this in the server logs:

```
Started POST "/api/user_profiles/1/playlists/8/song_references" for ::1 at 2016-10-11 20:50:47 -0400
Processing by Api::SongReferencesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"playlist_id"=>"8", "song_id"=>4, "user_profile_id"=>"1", "song_reference"=>{"playlist_id"=>"8", "song_id"=>4}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "playlist_songs" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-10-12 00:50:47.752976"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-12 00:50:47.752976"]]
   (8.2ms)  commit transaction
Completed 201 Created in 19ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)
```

If I change the playlist_song_params in the song_references_controller.rb file so they read:

```
  def playlist_song_params
    params.require(:playlist_song).permit(:song_id, :playlist_id)
  end
```

I get a 400 BAD REQUEST ERROR, and I see this in the server logs:

```
Started POST "/api/user_profiles/1/playlists/8/song_references" for ::1 at 2016-10-11 20:50:47 -0400
Processing by Api::SongReferencesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"playlist_id"=>"8", "song_id"=>4, "user_profile_id"=>"1", "song_reference"=>{"playlist_id"=>"8", "song_id"=>4}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "playlist_songs" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-10-12 00:50:47.752976"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-12 00:50:47.752976"]]
   (8.2ms)  commit transaction
Completed 201 Created in 19ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)
```

Am I completely off-base as to how I should be going about saving my "playlist_songs" ?

If so, would anyone mind shedding a bit of light as to how I might go about configuring my strong_params, as well as how I should setup the "newSong" variable within the "$scope.saveSong" function?

Let me know if you need any other code in my project, and I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was able to get the playlist_song attributes to save by changing the playlist_song_params to the following:

```
def playlist_song_params
   params.permit(:playlist_id, :song_id)
end
```

I have no idea why this worked, so if anyone wants to shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.